# Ubuntu 16 doesn't recognize ng commands

Tags: angular, angular-cli

> The program 'ng' is currently not installed. You can install it by
>   typing: sudo apt install ng-common

I got no erros during installation, how can i fix this?

Edit: this happens when i try to run `ng new PROJECT_NAME`

Comment: Check `which ng` and if it is in your path.

Comment: did you get this to work?

Answer (score 19):

first in whichever directory you are in come back to home directory

> ie prashanth:~/Projects/angular2$ cd
>    ---->
>   prashanth:~$

then enter the following commands

> npm bin -g
>   outputs---> /usr/bin

next,

> sudo npm rm -g @angular/cli

clear npm cache,

> npm cache clear

then install angular-cli globally,

> sudo npm install -g @angular/cli

now you r good to go, type

> ng -v

and check the version installed.

Comment: Do NOT use sudo for NPM, I repeat: DO NOT USE sudo for npm!!

Comment: What risks are posed when running `npm` commands as sudo?

Comment: I would also like to know: what are the risks to using ```npm``` with ```sudo```? I just did it... @GuyT edit: A quick google turned up this useful article https://medium.com/@ExplosionPills/dont-use-sudo-with-npm-still-66e609f5f92

Answer (score 10):

The issue is not specific to Ubuntu version.

**Edit (26 Aug, 2018):**

Run `npm list -g --depth=0` and see if `@angular/cli@x.x.x` is present in the results.

If it isn't, then you've probably installed angular in local scope.

Install it in global scope with Robert's method mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38806815/5750640).

---

If it still doesn't fix the issue, then **reinstall angular** completely:

- `npm uninstall -g @angular/cli`
- `npm cache clear --force`
- `npm install -g @angular/cli`
- Replace `@angular/cli` with `angular-cli` if you've installed an older version of angular.

If you have installed `node` by any other method, follow Edgar's method [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47354517/5750640).

Answer (score 7):

That's not how you install the angular command-line tools.
You need to use npm to install them globally:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

If you want to install a particular version then use

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@x
```

(where `x` is version number for example. `npm install -g @angular/cli@7`)

Comment: Do you try? sudo npm install -g @angular/cli

Answer (score 6):

To install it globally, Just run

> npm install -g @angular/cli

After that run this command

> npm link @angular/cli

and it should work seamlessly and If still not works

> restart your system

---

Answer (score 4):

This command worked fine for my issue. **press ctrl+T**. Then run the following command.

Before that make sure you have installed node js in your local machine. for the verification, you have already installed node js, run the following command on your terminal.

```
node --version
```

[image]

Then install ng packages by running following commands on your terminal.

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

[image]

```
npm link @angular/cli
```

[image]
Then it will work fine. for the verification of work, fine run any ng command. for example, run on the terminal following command.

```
ng --version
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem because I downloaded and installed nodejs from the tar.gz package. I did the following to solve the problem:

1. Deleted the nodejs folder (mine was in Downloads)
2. Deleted npm and node from my path by removing then from ~/.profile
3. Install nvm as explained [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-node-js-on-ubuntu-16-04)
4. Install npm using `sudo apt install npm`. then upgrae using `npm install -g npm@latest`
5. Updgrade node to lates using `nvm install --lts`
6. Run `npm install -g @angular/cli`.

This should fix the problem. If you are still unable to use ng, then check your environmental variables to make sure it has been correctly set.

Answer (score 2):

By running this command:

> npm bin -g

you can see where the npm installs packages globally, including the `angular/cli`. When you run this command you'll probably see something like this in the output:

```
/some/directory/bin
(not in PATH env variable)
```

If so, as you can see in the parentheses, it's saying that this directory is not in PATH env! So what you need to do is to either change this directory to another directory (which is in the PATH env, e.g usr/bin) by `npm config set prefix` command:

```
npm config set prefix '/usr'
```

or to add this directory to the PATH env, by any way you know! But to do so for example you can **add this line of code to the `~/.profile` file:**

```
export PATH=/some/directory/bin:$PATH
```

and then **restart your computer.**

Answer (score 0):

As it says [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/2536) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40549174/3234721) it might be a memory issue. After I increased RAM from 1024 to 2048 the error gone.

Answer (score 0):

As said [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1192) by [manuelfink](https://github.com/manuelfink) it is a memory issue. Installation needs at least 1GB ram.

Do not forget to run `npm cache clean` between every attempt.

Comment: I have the same problem, running on a machine with sufficient ram.

Comment: Uninstall all npm dependencies and run: npm cache clean.

Answer (score 0):

The official [Angular-cli](https://cli.angular.io/) documentation say that the installation command is:

```
$ npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Again, in the official [github repo, installation section](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#installation) is the same command

I had the same problem on **ubuntu 16**, and after run with **sudo**, the npm install in that way, everithing goes ok

Comment: It works with sudo because you have installed npm with sudo. This is a bad practice and should not used at all!

Answer (score 0):

There is no error in node_modules permission

Actually angular 2 is updated to **@angular/cli** from **angular/cli**

If you mistakenly install angular 2 using

> > npm install -g angular-cli

then run

1. > > npm install -g @angular-cli

and then

2. > > npm install -g @angular-cli/latest

**Thanks**

Answer (score 0):

Below steps solved my issue,

1. Upgrade npm to latest

   npm install -g npm@latest

2  Remove angular-cli if already exists

npm remove -g angular-cli

3. Clear cache

   npm cache clean

   For latest version of npm you don't have to do this. It will correct itself. You can verify using ,

   npm cache verify

4 Install angular/cli again

npm install -g angular-cli

Answer (score 0):

It works for me
The problem like **Refuse to delete old ng file** means rename the ng file using `mv target file new_file_name` and installl`sudo npm install --unsafe-perm -g @angular/cli`.

[click here to source](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/7735)

Answer (score 0):

If nothing works, try out this simple step mentioned at https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10728 bu 'Jikaworld'. Then try the remianing commands for installing angular. It should work.

```
sudo npm install -g @angular/cli --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this command.
It will work perfectly.

```
sudo npm install --unsafe-perm -g @angular/cli
```

Answer (score 0):

If you installed Angular CLI using **YARN**, you must do it globally. Otherwise you get this error. So the fix is:

```
sudo yarn global add @angular/cli
```

Then check your Angular version by

```
ng --version
```

**Linux PopOS (Debian/Ubuntu)**

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you have the ng-common package installed on your system, which also provides the ng executable:

http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/all/ng-common/filelist

If you are not using ng-common then remove it using sudo apt remove ng-common

then remove node cache

and give a path to in .bashrc or .profile

alias='path/to/node_modules/angular-cli/bin/ng'

Answer (score -1):

You have the wrong package:

Just

`sudo apt remove ng-common`

and

`npm install -g @angular-cli`

Restart your PC or Terminal