# Can't install angular-cli

Tags: angularjs, angular, npm, angular-cli

`angular-cli` just quits during installation:

```
(myapp)vagrant@myapp-local:/vagrant$ sudo npm install -g angular-cli
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@1.2.3: graceful-fs v3.0.0 and before will fail on node releases >= v7.0. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible. Use 'npm ls graceful-fs' to find it in the tree.
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated lodash-node@2.4.1: This package is discontinued. Use lodash@^4.0.0.
(myapp)vagrant@myapp-local:/vagrant$ l mapToRegistry uri https://registry.npmjs.org/serve-static

(myapp)vagrant@myapp-local:/vagrant$ ng
The program 'ng' is currently not installed. To run 'ng' please ask your administrator to install the package 'ng-common'
```

It seems I have latest versions of both node and npm:

```
(myapp)vagrant@myapp-local:/vagrant$ npm -v
3.10.9
(myapp)vagrant@myapp-local:/vagrant$ node -v
v6.9.1
```

Comment: You have installed using sudo so try `sudo ng`

Comment: facing same issue:
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$ sudo npm cache clean
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$ sudo npm uninstall -g angular-cli
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$ sudo npm install -g angular-cli
........
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$ : sill mapToRegistry uri https://registry.npmjs.org/selenium-webdriver

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resolved: So the issue was of memory of vagrant machine I increased it and it worked.

```
config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
    vb.memory = "2048"
end
```

At last step I had to do:

```
sudo ln -s   /home/vagrant/node-v6.9.1-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/bin/ng /usr/bin/ng
```

Comment: So it's not just me. Thanks. You probably should use it just as comment to my question, so that I could flag it as important because it's not an answer after all.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that NPM3 is needed. It's not currently mentioned on the readme check this [link](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/pull/1748). Just execute `npm install -g npm3` and then use `npm3` in place of `npm` to install or just update `npm` to the latest version. hope this will work.

*Updated*

1. Try to clean cache - `npm cache clean`,
2. Uninstall angular-cli - `npm uninstall -g angular-cli`
3. Install again `npm install -g angular-cli`.
4. Worse case install `angualr cli` with a `-force` flag like this - `npm install -g -f angular-cli`

Comment: I think there's no difference between using `npm3` command instead of `npm` if I already have npm=3.10.9 installed as shown in my question. Anyway, I tried to do what you advised and it didn't work.

Comment: @DmitryMikhaylov Try to clean cache `npm cache clean`, uninstall angular-cli `npm uninstall -g angular-cli` & install again `npm install -g angular-cli`. Worse case install angualr cli with a -force flag like this `npm install -g -f angular-cli`

Comment: Thanks, but result is the same after I cleaned cache, removed the angular-cli and reinstalled it with `-f` option